# wxPython centering a button and app crash on close

Tags: python, wxpython

Could someone help me kill two birds with one stone? I've been trying to center a button in my wxPanel for a little while and can't seem to figure it out. I've tried different attributes such as `wx.CENTER` and `wx.ALIGN_CENTER` and `wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL`, but just can't seem to get the button to move to the center of the panel. The button I'm trying to center is `set_button` in the `add_unit_pane` method.

Also, when I click the X button to close the program, the program crashes. Am I not handling the close event correctly?

Could someone point out where I'm wrong?

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kw) 
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.on_close_window)

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        panel_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        panel_sizer.Add(self.add_unit_pane(panel, panel_sizer), 0, wx.EXPAND, border=5)
        panel.SetSizerAndFit(panel_sizer)

        self.Show()

    def on_close_window(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

    def add_unit_pane(self, panel, panel_sizer):
        """ Creates the Unit Measurement panel """
        unit_panel = wx.StaticBox(panel, -1, 'Unit of Measurement')
        unit_panel_sizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(unit_panel, wx.VERTICAL)

        # Create horizontal row of widgets 1
        hbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        st1 = wx.StaticText(panel, label='UNIT:')
        unit_choices = ['in (INCHES)',
                        'cm (CENTIMETERS)',
                        'mm (MILLIMETERS)'
                        ]
        unit_cb = wx.ComboBox(panel, -1, '100%',
                                     choices=unit_choices,
                                     style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN|wx.CB_READONLY)
        unit_cb.SetValue('mm (MILLIMETERS)')

        hbox1.Add(st1)
        hbox1.AddSpacer(5)
        hbox1.Add(unit_cb)

        # Create horizontal row of widgets 2
        hbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        st2 = wx.StaticText(panel, label='Pixels per selected unit:')
        tc1 = wx.TextCtrl(panel)

        hbox2.Add(st2)
        hbox2.AddSpacer(5)
        hbox2.Add(tc1)

        # Create horizontal row of widgets 3
        hbox3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        set_button = wx.Button(panel, -1, 'Set')
        hbox3.Add(set_button, 0, wx.CENTER)

        # Add all other sizers to the main unit_panel_sizer
        unit_panel_sizer.Add(hbox1)
        unit_panel_sizer.AddSpacer(5)
        unit_panel_sizer.Add(hbox2)
        unit_panel_sizer.AddSpacer(5)
        unit_panel_sizer.Add(hbox3)

        # Fit all widgets to the sizer
        unit_panel.SetSizerAndFit(unit_panel_sizer)

        # Return the unit_panel_sizer
        return unit_panel_sizer

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ex = wx.App()
    Example(None, -1, "Centering Button", size=(250,150))
    ex.MainLoop()
```

Thank you,
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the line where you add hbox3 to be

```
unit_panel_sizer.Add(hbox3,0,wx.CENTER)
```

also comment out

```
unit_panel.SetSizerAndFit(unit_panel_sizer)
```

that should fix your crashing

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Any idea why doing `unit_panel.SetSizerAndFit(unit_panel_sizer)` crashes it only when closing?

Comment: no idea it should jsut crash when you do that probably since StaticBoxSizers are assigned their master or whatever when you instansiate them